# JS slider - is it possible to hyperlink my images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I've found some code for a simple img slider but I can't seem to hyperlink the images.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.slider :first-child').appendTo('.slider').show();
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.slider :first-child').hide().appendTo('.slider').fadeIn(1000);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.js .slider img { display: none; }
.js .slider img:first-child { display: block; }

.slider {
 position:relative;
}

.slider img {
 max-width: 980px;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="http://unsplash.it/375/150"></a>
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/375/148">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/375/149">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/375/152">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/375/151">
</div>
```

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="../files/images/banners/01.png"></a>
```

Also, less importantly, the first image seems to take ages (about 10 seconds) to move to the next one then the change every 3 seconds after that. Can anyone see anything wrong with the code that would make the first one hang?

Oh, and I know very little about JS :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The hyperlink works for me, if you click on it you do not get any response at all?

Comment: Nope, none at all. The mouse cursor doesn't even change to indicate it's a  link.

Comment: I've just noticed, the link works when the page initially loads but as soon as the page has finished loading, it then just becomes an image.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following `issues` in you code

1. `.js .slider img` in your `css` part does not apply, in given code `.slider` is not in an element `having .js class`. So change it to `.slider img`. Similarly `.js .slider img:first-child` to `.slider a:first-child img`
2. you need to put your `<img> tag` in side `<a> tag` to enable hyper link.
3. you need to replace selector `$('.slider :first-child')` in `setInterval function` to `$('.slider a :first')`.
4. Image load take some time you can put your code in `$(window).load(function() {});`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ybz15c82/)**